# Set Up PayPal PreApproval in App without PayPal UI

Tags: cordova, paypal

The following server side example code from PayPal generates a preapproval key:

```
public string GetPreApprovalKey() {
    RequestEnvelope requestEnvelope = new RequestEnvelope("en_US");

    string returnUrl = "https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/ap_preapprove_payment/dotnet?success=true";
    string cancelUrl = "https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/ap_preapprove_payment/dotnet?cancel=true";

    string currencyCode = "USD";
    string startingDate = "2013-10-30";
    PreapprovalRequest preapproveRequest = new PreapprovalRequest(requestEnvelope, cancelUrl, currencyCode, returnUrl, startingDate);

    preapproveRequest.endingDate = "2014-10-30";


    Dictionary<string, string> sdkConfig = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    sdkConfig.Add("mode", "sandbox");
    sdkConfig.Add("account1.apiUsername", "jb-us-seller_api1.paypal.com");
    sdkConfig.Add("account1.apiPassword", "WX4WTU3S8MY44S7F");
    sdkConfig.Add("account1.apiSignature", "AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31A7yDhhsPUU2XhtMoZXsWHFxu-RWy");
    sdkConfig.Add("account1.applicationId", "APP-80W284485P519543T");

    AdaptivePaymentsService adaptivePaymentsService = new AdaptivePaymentsService(sdkConfig);
    PreapprovalResponse preapprovalResponse = adaptivePaymentsService.Preapproval(preapproveRequest);

    return preapprovalResponse.preapprovalKey;
}
```

Firstly, where does one get the `"account1.apiUsername"`, `"account1.apiPassword"`, `"account1.apiSignature"`, `"account1.applicationId"` ?

Secondly, and more importantly, PayPal tells you to redirect your user to:

```
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_ap-preapproval&preapprovalkey={preapproval.preapprovalKey}
```

I want to set up preapproval functionality in a PhoneGap app, but have this be unobtrusive. Can you set up PayPal preapprovals purely within your own UI rather than going through the PayPal UI?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [this tool](https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_login-api-run) to obtain your API username, password, and signature.  You can also find/generate them in your PayPal account profile.

To generate the Preapproval you will need to go through the redirect.  Unfortunately, there's no way to avoid that.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of :( Thanks for the link though, will accept as this was helpful. Thanks!

Comment: @angell Is it possible to autenticate the preapproval key by submitting a form ? I want to get the authentication status of preapproval key in  my notification url. So in order to pass the notification url, I need a form. Or how can I get the result of _ap-preapproval command ?